# Migrate SharePoint 2010 FBA Users to online SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, migration, forms-authentication, user-accounts

We have FBA users in SharePoint 2010 and entire project is moved to Online SharePoint 2013 , But now we need to move the FBA Users of sharepoint 2010 to online SharePoint 2013 .Can any one guide me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 1):

> you can't import directly your user accounts from SQL to Office 365 for use with SharePoint online
>
> There only 2 options to create/manage user accounts in Office 365:
>
> - directory synchronization : to sync your local AD with Office 365; all account management is done through AD
> - office 365 user management: user account creation and management is done through the Office 365 admin portal; you can do bulk import using CSV file
>
> according to your context, I'll recommend to export your SQL DB in a CSV file and then import it through the admin portal

[reference](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/59082.aspx)